# jsCall return value to outside of jquery ajax post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ajaxq

I want to get jquery ajax post request value to outside from the ajax function. my code is this and it return *`undefined`* as console output. How should fix it

```
function submit() {
    var outputFromAjax = submitViaPost('administrator/validationForInputValuesOfAddRole');

    console.log(outputFromAjax);
}

function submitViaPost(url) {

    var formData = $('form').serializeArray();

    var output;

    $.post(urlForPhp + '/' + url, formData, function (outputData) {
        output = outputData;
    });
    return output;
}
```

---

**Edited**

I changed my code to sync type ajax post request and check output. But it is not changed. here my code

```
function submit() {
    var outputFromAjax = submitViaPost('administrator/validationForInputValuesOfAddRole');

    console.log(outputFromAjax);
}

function submitViaPost(url) {

    var formData = $('form').serializeArray();

    var output;

    $.ajax({
        url: urlForPhp + '/' + url,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        async: false,
        method: 'POST',
        success: function (e) {
            output =  e;
        }
    });
    return output;
}
```

Comment: submitViaPost function returns immediately and the return value will be always undefined. you have to save the value after the post callback is completed using the done callback of post

Comment: So how I coded it? return value should goes to inside $.post function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Deferred jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/)

```
function submit() {
    submitViaPost('administrator/validationForInputValuesOfAddRole').then(function (outputFromAjax) {
        console.log(outputFromAjax);
    });
}

function submitViaPost(url) {
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    var formData = $('form').serializeArray();
    $.post(urlForPhp + '/' + url, formData, function (outputData) {
        dfd.resolve(outputData);;
    });
    return dfd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't return , make it a callback as `$.post` is async

```
function submit() {
    submitViaPost('administrator/validationForInputValuesOfAddRole', function(out){ //Result comes here
      var outputFromAjax = out;
      console.log(outputFromAjax);
    });
}

function submitViaPost(url , callback) { //Added callback
    var formData = $('form').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
    url: urlForPhp + '/' + url,
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    async: false,
    method: 'POST',
    success: function (e) {
        callback(e);
    }
 });
}
```